# A confusing sentence structure that uses "by example"

Tags: commas

Here is a sentence from an article by The Economist that talks about the Saudi revolution that has recently allowed women to drive:

*A more normal Saudi Arabia should moderate the Islamic world, **by example** and because the flow of petrodollars to zealots would slow.*

The sentence structure bothers me, especially the "by example" part and the comma that precedes it. At first, I thought "by example" is some sort of a bizarre phrase that somehow makes the sentence grammatical; after googling, I am inclined to say the sentence is a mistake. Or is it not?

How should I interpret the sentence?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the cited text is an example of [zeugma / syllepsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis). What we have here is two statements - *Saudi Arabia should moderate the Islamic world **by example***, and *Saudi Arabia should moderate the Islamic world **because the flow of petrodollars to zealots would slow***. Those two highlighted clauses have different *syntactic* roles, which makes it inherently clumsy to join the two by ***and***. It's not so bad as, say, *John and his driving licence expired last week*, but it's not good.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, I think the comma should come after ***example***, not ***world***. But as I said, it's not good even if the orthography is "fixed". An alternative "fix" would be to discard the word ***and***.

Answer (score -1):

I seems like it might have been translated. “More normal” seems redundant. I believe it should read: “Islamic world by example, and cause the flow of petrodollars to zealots to slow.”